# Allow blur (focus on other items - input field outside paper-dialog) of Polymer paper-dialog

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have an absolutely positioned element which is out side paper-dialog, (it is a body > div).
I have a few input fields in the `div` where I want to be able to enter some text,
but paper-dialog doesn't let it leave focus, referencing to [this](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/polymerelements/paper-dialog-behavior) link.

[Here](https://codepen.io/hsemarap/pen/pZrRjB) is the link to a codepen demonstrating the issue.
Try entering text in the input field (`#my_div`) before and after opening the paper-dialog with one of the buttons there

Due to this, `document.activeElement` is always `paper-dialog`, hence I can't enter text in the input field outside it. (`document.activeElement` is logged in the console on clicking anywhere)

So, when `paper-dialog` is open, I am not able to click/focus on the input elements in my `div`, is there a way around it ?

P.S: I am mostly looking for a solution without changing the polymer code (like handling events or changing config via dom properties), assume I am running a local custom JS script over the main site.

Answer (score 1):

**Without changing the Polymer code** try to catch the click on the input, and programmatically click on the open dialog button, like so:

```
  <div id="my_div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" />
  </div>
  <script>
          document.getElementById('my_div').onclick = function()       {
            document.querySelectorAll('x-dialog paper-dialog:not([aria-hidden="true"]) paper-button')[0].click();
            document.getElementById("my_div").firstElementChild.focus();
      }      
  </script>
```

Check the [codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBvPJP) and verify that its working as intended.

Comment: But that closes the Paper-dialog, I wish to keep it open and be able to enter text in the box

Comment: AFAIK the purpose of the paper-dialog is to prevent action on any other element "behind" it, and after a couple tries myself, I'm not sure if this can be achieved. If you want to show a message with an action button, but still enable the user to interact with buttons, inputs, etc in the main screen, have you considered using snackbar? https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/snackbar

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a workaround of appending the textbox inside paper-dialog with fixed positioning to it, and then restoring it to normal dom position on close of dialog

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way around it, 
I ended up using a workaround of appending the textbox inside paper-dialog with fixed positioning to it, and then restoring it to normal dom position on close of dialog

Comment: I'm having the opposite issue. I have a TextField in a sidebar that functions properly; however, when I click anywhere on the canvas it will not remove focus from the TextField. If I find a solution, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution for our problem. Hopefully this can help you as well.

```
new paper.Tool();

  let startDragPoint;

  paper.tool.onMouseDown = (event) => {
    document.getElementById('elementID').blur();
    startDragPoint = event.point;
  };
```